# Fetch User Meta Data

Tags: user-meta, activation

Table - **wp_usermeta**

```
user_id  meta_key      meta_value
10       login_status  0  
10       active_code   3f7431e226893f16cbe44424850d00ad
```

I need to select `user_id` where `login_status = 0` and `active_code = 3f7431e226893f16cbe44424850d00ad`

Ex: `SELECT user_id FROM usermeta WHERE active_code ='3f7431e226893f16cbe44424850d00ad' and login_status='0'`

Tried below query but no success.

```
$querystr = "
        SELECT $wpdb->usermeta.user_id, $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key
        FROM $wpdb->usermeta
        WHERE $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value = '3f7431e226893f16cbe44424850d00ad`
        AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value = '0' ";
```

How can I simply fetch the `login_status` value along with `active_code`.

Thanks

Comment: the SQL statement will be a bit more complex than this; is there a particular reason you're avoiding WP_User_Query?

Comment: I just do not want to save my activation_cdoe and login_status in wp_user table, but in usermeta. how its possible using WP_User_Query ?

Comment: the code you've provided is for retrieving data from the database, not storing it. please re-write your question clarifying exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: data is already stored at the time of registration. during login need to fetch that data and change status = active where code matches

Comment: that should be happening automatically afaik

Comment: You are trying to get users where the meta_value is both a specific number and zero, which isn't possible.  Did you mean OR?

Answer (score 0):

All of this can be done using `WP_User_Query`:

```
$users = new WP_User_Query(array(
    meta_query(
        array( 'key' => 'login_status', 'value' => '0' ),
        array( 'key' => 'active_code', 'value' => '3f7431e226893f16cbe44424850d00ad' )
    )
));
```

This will return a list of users that meet your requirements.  Then you can get the ids like so:

```
$user_ids = wp_list_pluck( $users->get_results(), 'ID' );
```